# Why do I get this error with \includepdf: "(\pdfsetmatrix): Unrecognized format"?

Tags: pdftex, pdfpages, compilation-error

This MWE produces a compile error:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My Title}
\author{First M. Last}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\lipsum

\newpage
\includepdf{myPDF}

\end{document}
```

Here is the exact error message (line 15):

pdfTeX error (\pdfsetmatrix): Unrecognized format.. \includepdf{myPDF}

I am compiling with MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.7029 (1.40.20) (MiKTeX 2.9.7000 64-bit).  This is within TeXstudio on Windows 10.  Does anyone know why I get this error or how fix/prevent/avoid it?

Comment: Sounds as if something is wrong with your myPDF.

Comment: I suppose it does, but I've tried a lot of different PDFs created in different ways.  Also, some of my coworkers can compile the code above, while others like me get the error message.  It's not a one-time occurrence.  This has gone on for over a year.

Comment: Do you get the error with `\includepdf{example-image-duck}`? If yes show the log-file. If not you will have to make one of the problematic pdf available.

Comment: Yes, I do get that error with `\includepdf{example-image-duck}`.  Also, I posted the files (including the log) here:  <https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mqWw6vTW6hLcQ5XygT0yk5dHPkIDoUE->

Comment: By the way, I tried the original code (with example-image-duck) on Overleaf, and it compiles without error.  Here is the link to the project:  <https://www.overleaf.com/read/nczfnrqsyvdw>.  Somehow, Overleaf's compiler must be handling this different from MikTeX.

Comment: Delete this file: D:/MZA_SVN/templates/LaTex/texmf\tex/latex\trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)

Comment: I deleted the file, and now MikTeX compiles it without error.  What made you suggest this?

Comment: In fact, I refreshed the file name database and put trig.sty back, and it still compiles without error.

Comment: Don't use this outdated trig.sty. It is 16 years older than the current version in miktex and obviously doesn't work anymore.